# Remove and add the items from one list to another at the specified index

Tags: java, arraylist

I have two `ArrayList`s :

```
ArrayList a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11.......100]
ArrayList b = [a1,a2,a3,a4,a5,a6,a7,a8,a9,a10.......a100]
```

remove the every 5th and 6th elements of `ArrayList` a like 5,6 11,12 and so on and to the `ArrayList` b.

and also remove every 6th and 7th item of `ArrayList` b like a6,a7,a13,a14 so on and add it to `ArrayList` a.

so my output `ArrayList`s would be.

```
 ArrayList a = [1,2,3,4,a6,a7,7,8,9,10,a13,a14,13,14,15,16,a20,a21 and so on]
 ArrayList b = [a1,a2,a3,a4,a5,5,6,a8,a9,a10,a11,a12,11,12 ,a15,a16,a17,a18,a19,17,18and so on]
```

so how can I achieve this?

I tried it but not in an exact way.

```
       int highAdded = 0;
    int normalAdded = 0;
    for (Iterator<BaseItem> iterator = mItems.iterator(); iterator.hasNext(); ) {
        BaseItem itemtype = iterator.next();
        if (itemtype.isHighlightPost()) {

            highAdded++;
            if (highAdded == 5) {
                normal.add(itemtype);
            } else if (highAdded == 6) {
                normal.add(itemtype);
                highAdded = 0;
            } else {
                highlighted.add(itemtype);
            }
        } else {
            normalAdded++;
            if (normalAdded == 6) {
                highlighted.add(itemtype);
            } else if (normalAdded == 7) {
                highlighted.add(itemtype);
                normalAdded = 0;
            } else {
                normal.add(itemtype);
            }
        }

    }
```

Thanks

Comment: I would suggest a loop, `ArrayList#add(int index, E element)`, and `ArrayList#remove(int index);`

Comment: You need to specify this better. It's not clear what the ordering of the new lists should be. Add some more to the "and so on" parts to clarify. The issue is that the gaps in `b` are bigger than the gaps in `a`, so the swaps aren't going to stay in sync.

Comment: @chiastic-security Right: especially what happens if you reach the end of list b with the larger increment?

Comment: Inserting into an `ArrayList` at an arbitrary position is not a cheap operation, by the way. What you're doing, if the lists are large, would be much quicker using a `LinkedList`. If you really want an `ArrayList`, you can convert it to one at the end.

Comment: @chiastic-security Why would you need insert?

Comment: @laune OP wants to remove from `a` and add into `b`, and vice versa. This appears to mean insertion in the middle. Look at the example outputs: they're mixtures of `a` and `b`. (It could be done by constructing new lists, of course; not clear whether that's what OP has in mind, but not how I interpreted it.)

Comment: @chiastic-security Doesn't it occur to you how you can avoid the costly remove and insert operations?

Comment: @chiastic-security, added the few more items(expected sequence) to the so on parts for more clarification.i ll post what i have tried also in my question .plz have a look at that,but in that way i m not achieving the output lists with proper indexes as expected.

Comment: @laune now it's been clarified, yes, you can avoid that by reassigning elements. Until this point, it had looked to me as though elements would need to be shifted left/right, but perhaps not. This is the problem with ambiguous specs :)

Comment: @chiastic-security OP just fell into the trap of thinking in terms of remove and insert. Except for the missing spec for unmatched pairs in list a, everything is accurate enough *in the sample output* (though not in the verbal description).

Comment: So you don't really want to move every 5th and 6th from `a`! You want to move 5, 6, 11, 12, 17, 18. These values are 6n-1 and 6n for each n. But lists are indexed from zero, so in fact you want to move elements numbered 6n-2 and 6n-1 for each positive integer n.

Comment: @chiastic-security thanks I fell into the 0 indexing trap, fixed the index calculations in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

this should do the job, note that here there is no removal, but it does replacements. Ensure that N is set so that no list sizes are exceeded.

```
/** Multiplier for a-list index */
private final static int M_A = 6;
/** Multiplier for b-list index */
private final static int M_B = 7;

{
   // ...
   final int n = Math.min( a.size() / M_A, b.size() / M_B );
   for ( int i = 1; i <= n; i++ ) {
      exchange( a, b, i * M_A - 2, i * M_B - 2 );
      exchange( a, b, i * M_A - 1, i * M_B - 1 );
   }
   // ...
}

private <T> void exchange( List<T> a, List<T> b, int aIndex, int bIndex ) {
   T elem1 = a.get( aIndex );
   a.set( aIndex, b.get( bIndex ) );
   b.set( bIndex, elem1 );
}
```

(edited to match 'specification' for index counters)
(edit 2, added also computation of n)

Comment: This isn't right at all. It would move elements 5, 6, 10, 12, 15, 18 from `a`, rather than 5, 6, 11, 12, 17, 18.

Comment: You also need to calculate N.

Comment: guys... I proposed some java code on how to solve the exchange of the entries in java in an efficient way. I'll leave to the poster of the question to figure out, how to compute N.

Comment: heh... bah, I never like to leave something unfinished. Added also computation of n

Comment: @Danilo Tommasina,+1 for the answer and its giving the error  java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 6, size is 6
            at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException  at this line  a.set( aIndex, b.get( bIndex ) );

Comment: My bad fixed the calculation of n, list size is 1 higher than the maximum index.

Answer (score 1):

you can done this through set() method of arraylist

```
public void arraylistproblem()
{
    ArrayList<String> a=new ArrayList<>();
    for(int i=1;i<=100;i++)
    {
        a.add(""+i);
    }

    ArrayList<String> b=new ArrayList<>();
    for(int j=1;j<=100;j++)
    {
        b.add("a"+j);
    }

    System.out.print("Arraylist a = ");
    for(int i1=0;i1<a.size();i1++)
    {
        System.out.print(a.get(i1)+",");
    }
    System.out.print("Arraylist b = ");
    for(int i1=0;i1<b.size();i1++)
    {
        System.out.print(b.get(i1) + ",");
    }

    int aIndex=4;
    int bIndex=5;
    for(int i=0;i<a.size();i++)
    {

        if(aIndex>=a.size() || bIndex>=b.size())
            break;

        String aTemp1=a.get(aIndex);
        String bTemp1=b.get(bIndex);

        /**
         * swap the values .. 5th of a-arraylist and 6th of b-arraylist
         */
        a.set(aIndex++, bTemp1);
        b.set(bIndex++, aTemp1);

        String aTemp2=a.get(aIndex);
        String bTemp2=b.get(bIndex);

        /**
         * swap the values .. 6th of a-arraylist and 7th of b-arraylist
         */
        a.set(aIndex, bTemp2);
        b.set(bIndex, aTemp2);

        aIndex=aIndex+5;
        bIndex=bIndex+6;
    }

    System.out.print("Arraylist a = ");
    for(int i1=0;i1<a.size();i1++)
    {
        System.out.print(a.get(i1)+",");
    }
    System.out.print("Arraylist b = ");
    for(int i1=0;i1<b.size();i1++)
    {
        System.out.print(b.get(i1)+",");
    }
}
```